# How to loop a function till a new mqtt message arrives?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, synchronization, mqtt, paho

I'm writing a mqtt app in C++ with Paho. I'm using Paho.mqtt C library that can be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/Cclient/).

When I receive a message in the callback function, it calls another function to print the message. I want to be able to loop that function until a new message arrives.

```
bool start = false;
void loopMessage(std::string message){
   start = true;
   while(start){
       std::out << "message: " << message;
   }
}
int messageArrivedCallback(mqtt message){
   start = false;
   loopMessage(message);
}
```

The code above is not working; I can receive one message and run the while loop in the `loopMessage` function. After that the client disconnects. I think this is because it is in blocking mode and the broker disconnects the client after the keep alive interval (I'm using MQTTClient). If I quickly send a new message before disconnection, the client doesn't receive it.

I tried to use the asynchronus client version (MQTTAsync) but it is giving me the same problem.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Paho client will start a thread to handle the network loop and collect new messages so just remove the `loopMessage` function and print the message in the `messageArrivedCallback`.

You should not make blocking calls (which is what this infinite loop does) in the `messageArrivedCallback` because it has to return to allow the client to continue to receive messages.

If you want to print the message content over and over agian until a new message arrives then you need to do it on a separate thread.

Comment: Hi! If there is a while loop in the callback function i think the callback can't receive new messages, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Janoshh: That doesn't make sense. Of course the callback function can receive new messages, but it can only receive one message at a time. It can't receive a second message until it's done with the first. And the callback is only done with a message when it returns.

Comment: @hardillb: Yes i meant: if the there is a while loop in the callback, the callback is never returning so it can't receive a new message. allright, i had the same idea but threading is mostly a bad solution and i was thinking there might be a better one

Comment: Threading is not bad, it's just not easy. It's also the only way to do what you want

Comment: So the asynchronus client isn't any better than the synchronus client for my example?

Comment: No, the async client doesn't block when connecting and publishing, it still expects you not to block on messages delivery

Comment: ahhhhhh, this is a useful thread no pun intended. Threading was the recommended way I do this but thought Id try and get away with just the while loop but it doesnt work. If the while loop for a topic is not finished it blocks the other messages for that topic as stated above.

Comment: could celery have been a solution to OP's problem?